# How to declare an array consisting of list items gloabal which can be initialized later?

Tags: android, spinner

I have two arrays of list items.I wanted to send its items to an Adapter according to some conditions. So i initialized it multiple times and applied condition to it which if true will send that number of items to Adapter.

Here is the Code to understand better

```
int images[];
    String levels[];

  @Override
       protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.cannon_spinner_numbers);


//// initialize all your visual fields
//          if (savedInstanceState != null) {
//              sp1.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("MySpinner1", 0));
//              // do this for each of your text views
//          }

          if (bundle.getString("classFrom").equals(TownHallNineActivity.class.toString())) {

           images[] = {R.drawable.cannon1,
                      R.drawable.cannon2,
                      R.drawable.cannon3,
                      R.drawable.cannon4,
                      R.drawable.cannon5,
                      R.drawable.cannon6,
                      R.drawable.cannon7,
                      R.drawable.cannon8,
                      R.drawable.cannon9,
                      R.drawable.cannon10,
                      R.drawable.cannon11,
                      R.drawable.cannon12,
                      R.drawable.cannon13,
                      R.drawable.cannon14
              };

              String levels[] = {"Level 1",
                      "Level 2",
                      "Level 3",
                      "Level 4",
                      "Level 5",
                      "Level 6",
                      "Level 7",
                      "Level 8",
                      "Level 9",
                      "Level 10",
                      "Level 11",
                      "Level 12",
                      "Level 13",
                      "Level 14",};

          }

if (bundle.getString("classFrom").equals(TownHallTenActivity.class.toString())) {

           images[] = {R.drawable.cannon1,
                      R.drawable.cannon2,
                      R.drawable.cannon3,
                      R.drawable.cannon4,
                      R.drawable.cannon5,
                      R.drawable.cannon6,
                      R.drawable.cannon7,
                      R.drawable.cannon8,
                      R.drawable.cannon9,
                      R.drawable.cannon10,
                      R.drawable.cannon11,
                      R.drawable.cannon12,

              };

              String levels[] = {"Level 1",
                      "Level 2",
                      "Level 3",
                      "Level 4",
                      "Level 5",
                      "Level 6",
                      "Level 7",
                      "Level 8",
                      "Level 9",
                      "Level 10",
                      "Level 11",
                      "Level 12"
                      };

          }
```

And then set theese items to Adapter

```
 SpinnerAdapter adapter=new SpinnerAdapter(this,levels,images);



          sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am getting this error while initializing ImageArray/String Array

[image]

It says unexpected token.Moreover is this the right approach to hide items from a spinner by sending only those items to adapter which is to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have commas in a places where they are not needed: after "Level 14" and after "R.drawable.cannon12". That is what is meant by "unexpected token".

I would recommend having an ArrayList with elements up to 12 (which both share) and then using **.add(element)** to add in the next two elements in the appropriate if statement.